# Angular 5 defining child routes inside modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

I have Angular 5 application with following structure:

```
/-app module
   /--- settings dashboard component
/-settings A module
   /--- list A component
   /--- edit A component
/-settings B module
   /--- list B component
   /--- edit B component
```

I want to setup routes for this modules and components:

```
'settings' -> settings dashboard component (defined in app-routing.module.ts)
'settings/A' -> list A component (defined in a-routing.module.ts)
'settings/A/edit' -> list A edit component (defined in a-routing.module.ts)
'settings/B' -> list B component (defined in b-routing-module.ts)
'settings/B/edit' -> list B edit component (defined in b-routing-module.ts)
```

is it possible? I tried combination of routes with child but it's not working.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about what’s the current issue you’re facing and what are you trying to resolve? Also maybe including your routing setup will help.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have a routing example here that may help: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I see your concern here, but yes, it is possible.

app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'settings',
  component: SettingsDashboardComponent
}, {
  path: 'settings/A',
  loadChildren: './a/a.module#AModule'
}, {
  path: 'settings/B',
  loadChildren: './b/b.module#BModule'
}];
```

a-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AListComponent
}, {
  path: 'edit',
  component: AEditComponent
}];
```

b-routing is like a-routing.

The fact that the route contains a partial of the other one doesn't matter, it goes for a full match.  It does care about partials for lazy loading, but only in so far as it can match the full route somewhere in the lazy loaded routes.